# phpMyAdmin JavaScript error when using designer feature

Tags: mysql, javascript, phpmyadmin

When I try to use the designer feature in phpMyAdmin I get this error 'A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?'. This freezes the entire site and I have to log out and back in to regain functionality. I have been searching the internet for hours with no working solution. I have tried disabling extensions, changing browsers, changing computers, clearing cache/cookies/etc, and I didnt change any default settings. To be clear my host is NFO and phpMyAdmin does not have root access, but I don't think this should matter because I have had the designer feature working on other cheap hosts in the past that didn't give root file access. I just barely got this host and haven't tried using the designer feature until just now. The version is 4.8.3 and is the newest version the host offers.

Comment: Hello,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPYLbaXa35o .
Have you tried update the phpmyadmin version?

Answer (score 0):

[Super useful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPYLbaXa35o)

This video didn't answer my exact problem but this video is super helpful! I found out that the code that you need to execute to enable this by default tries to create the necessary database. Since I am using a host I needed to create the database manually and change the name of the database in the create_tables.sql file.